# Can I turn off validation for URL field

Tags: 2010, ssom

Maybe it is a strange question, but is it possible to prevent the validation of a URL entered in a URL field?
The link in the URL field points to a Sharepoint site in the same site collection, but only will be created later:

```
ListItem("URL") = "MySiteCollection/Customers/NewCustomer"
```

`NewCustomer` is created with a different process the link must be there before the site is created. I tried to disable field validation like:

```
Dim fldURL As SPField = ListItem.Fields("URL")
fldURL.ValidationFormula = ""
fldURL.ValidationMessage = ""
fldURL.Update(True)
```

But I get an error message that

> This field does not support validation.

So, can I put an invalid link to the URL field somehow?